# Sort bib entries using apsrev4-1 style according to author last name

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm using apsrev4-1 style for my thesis and need to sort the bibliography entries according to last name of the first author. I have tried various methods but no success. Here is how my `.tex` file looks:

```
\documentclass
    [phd,
     smplmath,
     indenttoc]
    {iitmdissertation}
\def\MakeUppercaseUnsupportedInPdfStrings{\scshape}
```

where the `iitmdissertation.sty` contains the following

```
\RequirePackage[numbers, square, sort&compress]{natbib}
```

Currently the references in the bibliography appear in the order of appearance. I want them to appear alphabetically in the order of last name of the author. I am open to modifying the [apsrev4-1.bst](https://github.com/compholio/jabbrv/blob/master/apsrev4-1.bst) file if required.

Comment: `apsrev4-1` sorts by order of appearance. Use a different style. By the way, this bib style omits titles, which is definitely unusual in theses where full citations are expected.